# Is there a list of which ciphers suites BoringSSL lib supports?

Tags: ssl, boringssl

I'm trying to get a comprehensive list of all supported ciphers suites by BoringSSL. I didn't find that in the docs.

Looking into the source I found the file `ssl_cipher.cc` and the constant `SSL_CIPHER` with the IANA names of ciphers:

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
```

Are those all the supported ciphers?

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, no one replied, brother. Please take a look here：https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1550981-ssl_cipher_suite_values

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35380198)